# Where is database query implemented in MVP pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, mvp

I need to implement MVP pattern in JAVA for my semester project and I am not able to figure out where the services are implemented in MVP.

Comment: Have you searched Google for this? Show some links that you went through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might now the rule that **model** provides services to **presenter** and **presenter** provides services to **views** not vice versa thus **views** using the **presenter** and **presenter** using the **model** layer.

In perfect world you will use DTOs to transfer the data between layers.

**Model** - serve to get the data from database, files or other data source

- Enyties
- DAOs

**Presenter**(Controler) - preparing the data from model to presentable form for view

- Services
- Beans

**Views** - take data from presenter and display them

- Beans can bellow here as well
- Templates

Comment: "So we can create services and query are written in services, form presenter we can call services".  is this right?

Comment: You should have CRUD methods in your DAOs. Services which wrapping the methods from DAOs and if it is need in sevices manage the transactions over these methods. If you are using JPA you can ommit the DAOs because JPA is so far your DAO layer.